# How to implement ivprobit in panel data in R?

Tags: binary, instruments, panel-data

I know ivprobit function can be implemented well in cross-sectional data, and I see we can use cluster() command if we have panel data in Stata. However, what can I do in R in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use the "ivprobit" function in "ivprobit" package in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54806589/how-can-i-use-the-ivprobit-function-in-ivprobit-package-in-r)

Comment: Hi ponponlu and welcome to SO ! Google yields some nice results with a "ivprobit R" search as [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54806589/how-can-i-use-the-ivprobit-function-in-ivprobit-package-in-r) and [that one from stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96657/iv-probit-in-r).